# How to check if Monkey accepts the seed?

Tags: android, performance, android-studio, stress-testing, monkey

I'm taking measurements with Monkey on Android. For the type of analysis I have to do, I need to generate the same sequence of events for each experiment. So, in every experiment, I always use the adb shell monkey command with the same seed. For instance:

```
while true; do


adb shell monkey -p com.android.chrome -s 1 --pct-appswitch 100 --ignore-crashes --ignore-timeouts --ignore-security-exceptions --monitor-native-crashes -v -v 1 


sleep 1
adb shell monkey -p com.facebook.katana -s 1 --pct-appswitch 100 --ignore-crashes --ignore-timeouts --ignore-security-exceptions --monitor-native-crashes -v -v 1


sleep 1
adb shell monkey -p com.google.android.apps.maps -s 1 --pct-appswitch 100 --ignore-crashes --ignore-timeouts --ignore-security-exceptions --monitor-native-crashes -v -v 1 

done
```

The applications I launch are ten in total. However, it seems to me that the same sequence of events is not always generated. Is there any way to check if Monkey always generates the same sequence of events with each experiment? Is it correct to put the seed immediately after the application name?

Comment: change the number of events down to 5, and watch what the monkey does (looks like the number of events is 1? right now, bit strange)

Comment: Also try another number instead of 1 i.e. `-s 321` , 1 might be a special value